# Filter by extensions and file names

Tags: php, image

I have this code located below. I have noticed that I am starting to add more files which is files to be filtered which is fine however now I will like to add extensions.

So anything which is a jpg, mp3 or vtr would also be excluded. TO be honest I am not sure 100% how to approach this. I have tried with no success.

```
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $file == 'index.htm'  OR $file == 'index.html' OR $file == 'jpg'){}else{
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file)
{
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..', 'index.htm', 'index.html')) && !in_array(substr($file, -4), array('.jpg', '.mp3', '.vtr')))
    {
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);     
    }
}
?>
```

Just add the excluded extensions in the second `in_array()`, as long as the extension name is 3 characters long.

If you want to exclude files with a extension that is 4 characters long, add another in_array. For example :

```
<?php
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file)
{
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..', 'index.htm', 'index.html')) && !in_array(substr($file, -4), array('.jpg', '.mp3', '.vtr')) && !in_array(substr($file, -5), array('.jpeg', '.mpeg')))
    {
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);     
    }
}
?>
```

The substr will extract the extension name, and !in_array will make sure the extension name is not in the given list of extensions.

Comment: I gave it a go but for some reason it did not work. I am looking to through the code to see if I can see something.

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis, I edited my code ;)

Comment: Ok, still going through it. It seems still not to work. Just making sure it is not me.

Comment: Parsing extension with `substr` is an overkill and not elegant at all. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. I think it's pretty straightforward and easy to maintain:

```
// put those two somewhere in conf file or something
$allowedFiles = array(
    ".",
    "..",
    "index.htm",
    "index.html"
);

$allowedExtensions = array(
    "mp3",
    "jpg",
    "png"
);

foreach($folder as $file){
    $filePathInfo = pathinfo($file);
    if(!in_array($filePathInfo["basename"], $allowedFiles) && !in_array($filePathInfo["extension"], $allowedExtensions)) {
        // do what you want here...
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php) for this. This will work even if your file has multiple `.` in it (like `index.html.bak`):

```
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    preg_match('/^(.*)(\..*)$/', $file, $matches);

    $fileNamePart = $matches[1]; // Just the part before the extension
    $fileExtension = $matches[2]; // The extension (like '.mp3')
     if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file == 'index.htm' || $file == 'index.html' || $fileExtension == '.mp3' || $fileExtension == '.jpeg' || $fileExtension == '.jpg' /* || other conditions ... */ ) {
        // ...
    } else {
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);   
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arthor Fixed a typo in an earlier version of this, but this should do what you want it to do. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$notAllowedFileTypes = array(
    "mp3",
    "jpg"
);

$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if(isAllowed($file)){
      //...
    }
}

function isAllowed($file)
{
    $notAllowedTypes = implode("|", $notAllowedFileTypes);
    preg_match("/^.*(\.(" . $notAllowedTypes . ")?)$/", $file, $matches);

    return count($matches) === 0;
}
```